# Cassandra - >500mb CSV file produces ~50mb size table?

Tags: cassandra

I am new to Cassandra and trying to figure out how sizing works. I created a keyspace and a table. I then generated a script to create 1 million rows in java into a csv file and insert it into my database. The CSV file was ~545 mb in size. I then loaded it into the database and ran **nodetool cfstats** command and received this output. It says the total space used is 50555052 bytes ( ~50 mb). How can this be? With overhead of indexes, columns, etc how can my total data be smaller than just the raw CSV data (not just smaller, but so much smaller)?  Maybe I am not reading something here correctly, but does this seem right? I am using Cassandra 2.2.1 on a single machine.

```
Table: users
        SSTable count: 1
        Space used (live): 50555052
        Space used (total): 50555052
        Space used by snapshots (total): 0
        Off heap memory used (total): 1481050
        SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.03029072054256705
        Number of keys (estimate): 984133
        Memtable cell count: 240336
        Memtable data size: 18385704
        Memtable off heap memory used: 0
        Memtable switch count: 19
        Local read count: 0
        Local read latency: NaN ms
        Local write count: 1000000
        Local write latency: 0.044 ms
        Pending flushes: 0
        Bloom filter false positives: 0
        Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
        Bloom filter space used: 1192632
        Bloom filter off heap memory used: 1192624
        Index summary off heap memory used: 203778
        Compression metadata off heap memory used: 84648
        Compacted partition minimum bytes: 643
        Compacted partition maximum bytes: 770
        Compacted partition mean bytes: 770
        Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
        Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 0
        Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
        Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0
```

My Java code to generate the CSV file looks like this:

```
try{

            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFileName);
            for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){


            writer.append("Username " + i);
            writer.append(',');
            writer.append(new Timestamp(date.getTime()).toString());
            writer.append(',');
            writer.append("myfakeemailaccnt@email.com");
            writer.append(',');
            writer.append(new Timestamp(date.getTime()).toString());
            writer.append(',');
            writer.append("eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ");
            writer.append(',');
            writer.append("eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ");
            writer.append(',');
            writer.append("eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ");
            writer.append(',');
            writer.append("tr");
            writer.append('\n');

            }   
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Not sure what your data looks like but if the CSV is full of commas and quotation marks you could see some savings

Comment: I am new to Cassandra too and I just copied over a ~14GB csv with ~23M records with 50 fields. Cassandra is telling me it is only ~158MB on disc.. Waiting for it to replicate across my nodes and then I am going to try some queries to make sure its all there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I thought of the biggest 3 pieces of data:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ
```

and thought they are the same maybe Cassandra is compressing them, even though it said it is only a ratio of 3%. So I changed my Java code to produce different data.

```
public class Main {

    private static final String ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        generateCassandraCSVData("users.csv");

    }

    public static String randomAlphaNumeric(int count) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while (count-- != 0) {
        int character = (int)(Math.random()*ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.length());
        builder.append(ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.charAt(character));
        }
        return builder.toString();
        }


    public static void generateCassandraCSVData(String sFileName){

    java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();


        try{

            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFileName);
            for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){



            writer.append("Username " + i);
            writer.append(',');
            writer.append(new Timestamp(date.getTime()).toString());
            writer.append(',');
            writer.append("myfakeemailaccnt@email.com");
            writer.append(',');
            writer.append(new Timestamp(date.getTime()).toString());
            writer.append(',');
            writer.append("" + randomAlphaNumeric(150) + "");
            writer.append(',');
            writer.append("" + randomAlphaNumeric(150) + "");
            writer.append(',');
            writer.append("" + randomAlphaNumeric(150) + "");
            writer.append(',');
            writer.append("tr");
            writer.append('\n');


            //generate whatever data you want
            }   
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
             e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }

}
```

So now the data for those 3 large columns is all random strings, not the same anymore. This is what was produced now:

```
Table: users
        SSTable count: 4
        Space used (live): 554671040
        Space used (total): 554671040
        Space used by snapshots (total): 0
        Off heap memory used (total): 1886175
        SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.6615549506522498
        Number of keys (estimate): 1019477
        Memtable cell count: 270024
        Memtable data size: 20758095
        Memtable off heap memory used: 0
        Memtable switch count: 25
        Local read count: 0
        Local read latency: NaN ms
        Local write count: 1323546
        Local write latency: 0.048 ms
        Pending flushes: 0
        Bloom filter false positives: 0
        Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
        Bloom filter space used: 1533512
        Bloom filter off heap memory used: 1533480
        Index summary off heap memory used: 257175
        Compression metadata off heap memory used: 95520
        Compacted partition minimum bytes: 311
        Compacted partition maximum bytes: 770
        Compacted partition mean bytes: 686
        Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
        Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 0
        Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
        Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0
```

So now the CSV file is again ~550mb and my table now is ~550mb too. It seems then if non key column data is the same (low cardinally) Cassandra it compressed this data very efficiently somehow? If this is the case, this is a very important concept (one I have never read before) to know when modeling your database as you can then save a lot of storage space if you keep this mind.